# PowerShell isolating parts of strings

Tags: regex, powershell

I have no experience with regular expressions and would love some help and suggestions on a possible solution to deleting parts of file names contained in a csv file.

Problem:

A list of exported file names contains a random unique identifier that I need isolated. The unique identifier has no predictable pattern, however the aspects which need removing do. Each file name ends with one of the following variations:

*V, -V, or %20V followed by a random number sequence with possible spaces, additional "-","*" and ending with .PDF

examples:

GTD-LVOE-43-0021 V10 0.PDF
GTD-LVOE-43-0021-V34-2.PDF
GTD-LVOE-43-0021_V02_9.PDF
GTD-LVOE-43-0021 V49.9.PDF

Solution:

My plan was to write a script to select of the first occurrence of a V from the end of the string and then delete it and everything to the right of it. Then the file names can be cleaned up by deleting any "-" or "_" and white space that occurs at the end of a string.

Question:

How can I do this with a regular expression and is my line of thinking even close to the right approach to solving this?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're trying to pull V10.PDF, V34-2.PDF, V02_9.PDF, and V49.PDF (I assumed the _V would be a part of it, too)?

Comment: trying now. I actually need to get rid of the file extension too. I already did a gci on the directories and exported to csv so removing them won't cause problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REGEX:   `[\s\-_]V.*?\.PDF`

Might do the trick.  You'd still need to replace away any leading - and _, but it should get you down the path, hopefully.

This would read as follows..

start with a `whitespace`, `-` OR `_` followed by a `V`.  Then take everything until you get to the first `.PDF`

Comment: YES!!!!! Worked flawlessly. Final code was a simple (gc path) -replace '[\s\-_]V.*?\.PDF',''